# Accessing new instances of UserControl in other methods

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a WrapPanel in my main window, lets call it MainWrap. And then I made a UserControl in a UserControl window (it's a school project and my UserControl has to be outside of a main window) which holds an image inside - named img.

Now when I click File->Open in my made up Menu, I open an OpenFileDialog and an image is selected. It makes a new instance of usercontrol, enters chosen image filename as usercontrol's image source. Then I add that usercontrol to my wrap panel in main window.

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Image files(*.png, *.jpg)|*.png;*.jpg|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        if(open.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            UserControl1 usrctrl1 = new UserControl1();
            usrctrl1.img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@open.FileName));
            MainWrap.Children.Add(usrctrl1);
        }
    }
```

This works OK - Everytime i load an image there is a new usercontrol, which has an invisible textblock with a red X inside it. If my usercontrol is rightclicked the textblock becomes visible.

What I want to do is next. I have a method Delete_selected in my main window. How can I access these UserControls from my MainWrap and check if their textblock is visible in Delete_Selected method?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please use MVVM to establish the communication between controls.

Comment: What @rajibdotnet is trying to say, and he's correct, is that your ViewModel should expose an ObservableCollection of objects with image URIs. You'd have a ListBox in your XAML, bind the ListBox's ItemsSource to the collection, and give the ListBox an ItemTemplate that would create the Image elements to display the images. You'd also give your ViewModel a SelectedItem property, and bind that to the ListBox's SelectedItem. Finally your ViewModel would expose a DeleteSelectedCommand, which removes SelectedItem from the collection. XAML is designed for that way of doing things.

Comment: The MVVM approach is well worth the steeper learning curve in the long run, if you plan to stick with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access those dynamically created user controls the similar way you added it to `MainWrap` :

```
//return all children of MainWrap those are of type UserControl1
var userControls = MainWrap.Children.OfType<UserControl1>();
foreach(UserControl1 u in userControls)
{
    //here you can inspect each user control via u variable, for example :
    if(u.MyTextBlock.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Or you can do filtering directly in single line, for example :

```
//return all children of MainWrap those are of type UserControl1...
//having visible textblock 
var userControls = MainWrap.Children
                           .OfType<UserControl1>()
                           .Where(o => o.MyTextBlock.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                           .ToList();
```